# According to these audio, am I a baritone or a tenor?

Tags: vocal-range

I am having trouble to find my voice type, I don't know if I am a baritone or a tenor. I have 30 years of age. My lowest note that I can support is G2, but my comfortable note starts at A2-Bb2. I feel like I strain at F#4, my second passaggio,so literally i am in my head  register at F#4, and I can mix up to A4-B4 in my good days.

Comment: Question as an answer - why do you feel the need to have a label put on the estimated range of your voice? What difference will it make to anything you sing in the future?  It's a good voice - just use it!

Comment: Just wanted to know if i can sing Tenor repertoire, because i would like to get some classical lessons for opera. I do not like Baritone repertoire in opera. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: A2-A4 is more of a baritone range in "classical" opera. Tenors need to be able to nail a string of C5s in an aria (without using falsetto) if they want to get the girl! But playing evil/comic roles as a baritone is also fun...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 1) it's a transcribing question, which is off topic, and 2) the links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

You "would like to get some classical lessons for opera"?  Well, do so.  Your vocal coach will hopefully be much more qualified to answer your question than strangers on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your voice to a lot of the Baritones and Tenors I've heard I'd have to say you're definitely closer to a Tenor.